# getLocation returns null, what am I missing?

Tags: java, twitter, processing, twitter4j

I am trying to get processing to show me the location of the twitter user by using `getLocation()` but all I get is `null`.

I suspect that I need to add something but do not know what.

I am using processing, a java platform and the `Twitter4J` library.

Comment: Can you post some code and show us what you've tried?

Comment: im using this tutorial: http://blog.blprnt.com/blog/blprnt/updated-quick-tutorial-processing-twitter

So im just getting the username and it's tweet. My code currently looks like this: http://codepad.org/2rZqqrAc

Comment: I've been looking at the source code for the Twitter4j API, and I can't find which class implements the `Tweet` interface.  Therefore, I can't be sure, but it seems to me that not all Tweets will have a Location associated with there, and therefore it's entirely possible that your call to `tweet.getLocation()` will return a null.  Are you sure that's not a perfectly valid response?

Comment: Got it fixed! 
The code looks like this: http://codepad.org/d6aL7zWW
Needed to change the class I was using to "user" not "tweet". Thanks for the help!

Comment: But that is the user's location in his profile. The GeoLocation of a tweet object contains where the User tweeted from. So, that is inaccurate.